# Capture PySpark error logs and traceback in project logger

Tags: apache-spark, logging, pyspark

I have a complex logger in my python project with multiple handlers (stream, file, ES etc.)

I want to capture the errors from pyspark py4j and write it in the log file created by the package logger.

I'm running pyspark in client mode hence my driver is outside the cluster. I create spark context in my code and run it by triggering the script and not by doing spark-submit.

After some research I came to know that I can use log4j.properties file to capture the logs, but I don't see how I can use it in the client mode solution.

I create spark context like this and do logs like this,

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import logging

logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info("creating spark context")

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myapp").getOrCreate()

logger.info("done")

# some pyspark related codes that throws an error
```

The project logger currently don't capture the logs from pyspark directly. I want to capture that logs as well using log4j in client mode.

How can I do that? Is there some spark related config that I can tweak while creating spark context?